# What does the Output means for getting Decision Function in Scikitlearn's SVM, when used 3 classes

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I referred following blog post while doing following code blocks https://prateekvjoshi.com/2015/12/15/how-to-compute-confidence-measure-for-svm-classifiers/ and I obtained following results. My intention find out the distance of a point from 3 classes in SVC of SVM in Scikit-learn, but I confused with the meaning described are there any solutions.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
x = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[1,4],[1,5],[2,4],[2,6]])
y = np.array([0,1,-1,-1,1,1,0])
classifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
classifier.fit(x,y)
classifier.decision_function([2,1])
```

last call give the following output of array of size 3

```
array([[ -8.88178420e-16,  -1.40000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+00]])
```

what does this array meant for, how can we use this array to find out which out three class (-1,1,0) the particular data point related for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the distance of the point `[2,1]` from the separating hyper-plane of SVM Classifier. So the first value is the distance of `[2,1]` from hyperplane separating the first class, so on and so forth. You can see the function's implementation [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/svm/base.py#L512) and read the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function) for more info.

**EDIT** : You can also check out [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-separating-hyperplane-py) as well.

Comment: @Mohammad Kashif, can you elaborate further what does 3 values respond further, I was confused, whether it is like first value is comparing (-1,0) classes, second is (0,1) and third is (1,-1) is it like that or any other ways....

Comment: @AmutheezanSivagnanam It is basicaaly the perpendicular distance of the point `[2,1]` from the hyperplane of class -1, followed perpendicular distance of the point `[2,1]` from the hyperplane of class 0 and finally perpendicular distance of the point `[2,1]` from the hyperplane of class 1.

Comment: @Mohammad Kashif, in my task need to predict which class it belongs to does this possible for 3 classes and using decision distance, btw I am tuned to obtain model in rbf kernel which says it give relative distance. Because when I tried decision function instead of predict or prediction probability it gives very low fscore and average values

Comment: "*the first value is the distance of [2,1] from hyperplane separating the first class*". I came into [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/18375) which elaborates on the topic and explains columns actually contain a relative position to **a pair of classes** (not to a single hyperplane). This is consistent with the fact that with 4 classes, the returned array has 6 columns (4x3/2 according to the documentation), which is the number of unique pairwise combinations of  classes. So in the OP case, the first column contains the measure relative to the pair of classes 1 and 2.